# Corsair CV450 PSU with RX 6500 XT GPU causes PC hard shutdown when gaming

Tags: power-supply, gpu, shutdown

Playing games such as Fallout 4 on Ultra, XCOM 2 on High or even Civilization 6 causes my computer to hard shutdown without any notification or BSOD verbose. It seems to only happens when playing games on demanding area for the GPU such as near bodies of water (lots of lighting reflections). I recorded the hard shutdown and it happens on 2:41 https://youtu.be/-RLHIPYS7k0?si=EFiyf7eVwdZv_HoM.

Here are my specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3200G
- GPU: MSI RX 6500 XT
- PSU: Corsair CV450
- RAM: 4GBx2 DDR4
- Storage: 128GB NVME

I assumed that the cause is PSU (450 Watt) that are supplying insufficient power to handle voltage spikes generated by the GPU. The average power needed for GPU is roughly 75-78W and CPU is 25-30W so there are quite a lot of spare power that can be used. I already check all kinds of PSU calculator websites and all of them also state that 450W is enough for the GPU.

Yes, I already monitor the temperature of the GPU and CPU while gaming and it seems normal (as you can see on the video). I also already tried undervolting the GPU but the problem still persists and causes FPS drop.

So the question is, what is likely the cause of the hard shutdown problem? Could buying a new GPU (say 550W with 80+ Gold) solves the problem? And can I claim warranty on the Corsair PSU because it seems that its not fulfills its promised wattage?

Thank you for any insights :D